# Django Pass value from dropdown menu to view

Tags: django, view, dropdown

I wrote an password generato and I want that the user can customize the length. How can I pass the value from the dropdown menu in the template to my views so I can create the password in the correct length.

Here is my views.py now:

```
def view_passwordgenerator(request):
    characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!@#$%^&*()")
    random.shuffle(characters)
    length = 10
    password = []
    for i in range(length):
        password.append(random.choice(characters))
    random.shuffle(password)
    pw = ("".join(password))
    context = {'password': pw, 'length': length}
    return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

- In `views.py` add this

  `length = int(request.GET.get('length'))   # UPDATED to cast int`
- In `html file` add the following:

  ````
  <form action="{% url 'view_passwordgenerator' %}">
  <select name="length"> 
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12" selected="selected">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
  </select> Length
  <input type="submit" value="Generate Password" class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>```
  ````
- Delete `length` from context

For full detailed example, visit my [Django Password Generator Github Repo](https://github.com/IT-Support-L2/Django3-PasswordGenerator)

Comment: this should work, how can I cast the String type from the
length = request.GET.get('length') to my int, 


this error appears:

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'` if I try to cast it with     for i in range(int(length)):

Comment: Fixed! totally forgot about it. My bad! Now it should be flawless. Enjoy.

Comment: in stackoverflow, if an answer matched your awaitings, then you should click on check mark to close the thread

Comment: already tried your fix, doesnt work

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

No worries I would have marked it as solved if it would work.

Comment: this is my edited code https://hastebin.com/alopevehip.csharp

Comment: did u saw the updated answer?

Comment: yeah I saw that, did you see my code from the hastebin?

Comment: I just need a way now to cast the value from the length into an correct int, the default way to do that with int(value) doesnt work the same error as above appears