# Django cast string to Integer

Tags: python, django, casting

I'm trying to cast a value from my template to the views with this code:

````
<form action="{% url 'view_passwordgenerator' %}">
<select name="length"> 
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12" selected="selected">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select> Length
<input type="submit" value="Generate Password" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>```
````

views

```
def view_passwordgenerator(request):
    length = int(request.GET.get('length'))
    for i in range(length):
        ...

    return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html')
```

This error appears:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

im just looking for a way to get the int out of the template without this error, maybe there is another way to cast it.

Comment: The `length` is not submitted. Likely you use that view both for rendering the form, and rendering a result based on that form?

Comment: so if I create a second view for the form what should be inside?

Comment: You don't need to create two views. But if you use the same view, you should make a distinction between requests *without* the `length` parameter, and the requests *with* a `length` parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Pass value from dropdown menu to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69588428/django-pass-value-from-dropdown-menu-to-view)

Comment: no HB21 I asked questions which you dont answered there, I got the same issue over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you render both the page with the form, and the page with the result when submitting that form with the same view.

As a result when you render that view for the first time, the `length` will be missing, you thus should check and only cast it to an `int` if we know it is part of the dictionary:

```
def view_passwordgenerator(request):
    if 'length' in request.GET:
        length = int(request.GET.get('length'))
        for i in range(length):
            # …
        return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html')
    return …
```

THis however is still nog very elegant, since people can use the URL to inject data into `request.GET`, and that is not per se an int. The most elegant way is likely to use a Django form:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    length = forms.IntegerField()
```

then you can check if the form validates:

```
def view_passwordgenerator(request):
    form = MyForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        for i in range(form.cleaned_data['length']):
            # …
        return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html')
    return …
```

You can render the picked item by passing it to the context:

```
def view_passwordgenerator(request):
    if 'length' in request.GET:
        length = int(request.GET.get('length'))
        for i in range(length):
            # …
        return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html', {'length': length})
    return …
```

and then render this with:

```
<select name="length"> 
    <option value="8" {% if length == 8 %}selected{% endif %}>8</option>
    <option value="9" {% if length == 9 %}selected{% endif %}>9</option>
    <option value="10" {% if length == 10 %}selected{% endif %}>10</option>
    <option value="11" {% if length == 11 %}selected{% endif %}>11</option>
    <option value="12" {% if length == 12 %}selected{% endif %}>12</option>
    <option value="13" {% if length == 13 %}selected{% endif %}>13</option>
    <option value="14" {% if length == 14 %}selected{% endif %}>14</option>
    <option value="15" {% if length == 15 %}selected{% endif %}>15</option>
    <option value="16" {% if length == 16 %}selected{% endif %}>16</option>
    <option value="17" {% if length == 17 %}selected{% endif %}>17</option>
    <option value="18" {% if length == 18 %}selected{% endif %}>18</option>
    <option value="19" {% if length == 19 %}selected{% endif %}>19</option>
    <option value="20" {% if length == 20 %}selected{% endif %}>20</option>
</select>
```

However I would advise to [*work with forms*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) these can be used to render, validate, and clean data.

Comment: if I use this code https://hastebin.com/babeveteto.csharp

the if statment never gets triggered, and the page doesnt work now, I think the way with the form view doesnt work for me because I want the form as a dropdown and not as an Integer Input Field

Comment: @FLYAX: exactly what happens if you hit the submit button?

Comment: nothing, the field where the password should be is still empty and the page stays like that

Comment: @FLYAX: the URL remains exactly the same? In that case, something is wrong with the submit logic. What if you se `<button type="submit">` itself? What if you add `method="get"` to the `<form>` tag?

Comment: thank you, it works now, I have another problem I want to have a default value which is just in the box if you enter the page the first time. If I have that selected this error appears 
https://hastebin.com/onukobodil.sql
btw also the code from the template

Comment: Should I just change the <option> tag to something diffrent or is there another way

Comment: You can set it to disabled, so `<option disabled>Select a length</option>`.

Comment: Okay, and the last thing is, everytime I click on the button the value is set to 8 again, no matter if the length is longer than 8, how can I make that the shown dropdown number is the same as the length

Comment: @FLYAX: you can pass it to the template and render conditionally a select (see edit), but I would advise to take a look at Django's forms, which will reduce the amount of boilerplate code significantly.